# VB.NET The report has no tables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this class called "SQLControl".
And I have a sub and function like this :

```
 Public Function ConnectionTest() As Boolean
    Try
        SQLConn.Open()
        SQLConn.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Public Sub LoadTable(LoadTableQuery As String) 'LoadTableQuery itu variable yang ada didalam si Sub LoadTable
    Try
        SQLConn.Open()

        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(LoadTableQuery, SQLConn) 'Pemakaian LoadTableQuery

        'Load SQL record untuk datagrid

        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
        SQLDataset = New DataSet
        SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

        SQLConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLConn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then i use my sub an function to this one :

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pbAdd.Click
    Me.Hide()
    MenuTambah.cbLokasiPeminjaman.SelectedIndex = 0
    MenuTambah.Show()
    If SQL.ConnectionTest = True Then
        SQL.LoadTable("SELECT * FROM Tabel_Pinjam")
        MenuTambah.DGVTambah.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
    Else
        MsgBox("Koneksi ke database gagal !")
    End If
End Sub
```

then I want to show the Datagridview called "DGVTambah" in "MenuTambah" Form dataset to my crystalreport, this code is in my "MenuTambah" Form :

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Dim myReport As New ReportDocument


    myReport.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Laporan.rpt")
    myReport.SetDataSource(DGVTambah.DataSource)
    LaporanViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport
End Sub
```

But it said "The report has no tables", why I am get this error? 
If no table, my datagridview called "DGVTambah" will not show any table, and my query works fine.
Thanks:)

Comment: Is the datagridview being populated prior to the report being run?

Comment: what you mean? my datagridview called "DGVTambah show table perfectly in "MenuTambah" Form, but not work in report

Comment: I am asking if your datagridview is populated when clicking the button for your report. Your datasource for you report is the datagridview rather than sql.sqldataset.tables (0)

Comment: So you set a breakpoint on the 'myreport.setdatasource' line and when it was hit, you hovered over .DataSource and . . .

Comment: @codeMonger123 yeah my DGV is populated when button click and run the sub called "LoadTable", Then I need do the same with my report

Comment: @peterG and populate my crystalreport document, so the result will be same like what my DGV show. If I am not wrong with your saying :P

Comment: Peter was stating if you put a breakpoint on your datasource what is it populating with

Comment: populated with my dataset like dataset I used in DGV